# How to change color of a sprite randomly

Tags: android, colors, libgdx

I wrote the following code:

```
int color = Color.argb8888(255, rand.nextInt(256), rand.nextInt(256), rand.nextInt(256));
stage.getBatch().setColor(color);
```

With this code I want to change the color of a sprite randomly. Unfortunately, the color of all sprites on the stage get changed but I want to declare which sprite I want to tint. How can I improve my code?

Comment: Every Actor is responsible for setting its color on the Batch in its own draw method. If it isn't supposed to be tinted, use Color.WHITE.

Comment: `Sprite` with `Stage` is not good way use `Image` instead of sprite

Comment: But how can I change the color of a Image? With the same method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer to use in this way :

```
final Image image=new Image(new Texture("badlogic.jpg"));
final Color colors[]=new Color[]{Color.YELLOW,Color.RED,Color.CYAN};
image.addAction(Actions.forever(Actions.sequence(Actions.delay(.2f),Actions.run(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                image.setColor(colors[MathUtils.random(colors.length-1)]);
            }
        }))));
stage.addActor(image);
```

Answer (score 2):

To change tint of a single sprite, use below code

```
Sprite mysprite;
Texture mytexture;
mytexture = new Texture("texture.png");
mysprite = new Sprite(mytexture);
mysprite.setColor(Color.WHITE.cpy().lerp(Color.BLACK, .5f));
```

this code changes white tint of sprite to black tint

Comment: If you want to change color randomly, place last line inside a Random() function

Answer (score 1):

```
Color color = new Color(rand.nextFloat(), rand.nextFloat(), rand.nextFloat(), 1f);
```

'rand.nextFloat()' is gives you a float between 0 and 1, so you can create random color like this.

Comment: Add some details rather than dumping the code only and do format.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, you could just set your color attribute that used as **vertex attributes** in shader back to normal color masking like this:

```
stage.getBatch().setColor(your_random_color);
stage.getBatch().draw(your_texture);
stage.getBatch().setColor(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,1.0f);
```

Please be noticed that I tried this way for drawing **TextureRegion**, but I think this would not be different with drawing **Sprite**.